# Running a function inside of a useMap() react leaflet function from another file on button click

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-leaflet

So I'm trying to make a weather animation function in react leaflet. I have everything set up so that the play/stop functions work within the function, but when I try bringing in a variable from outside to run these functions, react keeps rerendering the function and losing track of the timeOut ids used to loop the animation.

I also need to use the useMap() hook as this function runs in conjunction with other map functions

bare bones Weather function with the playStop function I want to call

```
export default function Weather(variable) {
   const map = useMap();
   animationTimer = false;

   function playStop() {
       if (!stop()) {
           play();
       }
   }

   function stop() {
       if (animationTimer) {
           clearTimeout(animationTimer);
           animationTimer = false;
           return true;
       }
       return false;
   }

   function play() {
       console.log(animationPosition)
       showFrame(animationPosition + 1);

       // Main animation driver. Run this function every 500 ms
       animationTimer = setTimeout(play, 500);
   }

   if (variable!== 1) {
       playStop()
   }

   return null;
}
```

Button in another file to start the animation

```
let [playStop, setPlayStop] = useState<number>(1); // How the variable is set up

<button onClick={() => setPlayStop(playStop + 1)}>Play/Stop Weather Animation</button>
<MapContainer bounds={flightPath} scrollWheelZoom={true} maxBounds={mapBounds} maxBoundsViscosity={1.0} minZoom={1}>
     <Weather variable={playStop} />
     <OtherComponents/>
</MapContainer>
```

I know the calling method is messy, but I couldn't figure out another way of doing it. This currently works to play the animation, but when I click the button again, the animation won't stop and I'm assuming it's because the function rerendered and lost what was stored inside animationTimer. Is there a way to stop the function from rerendering? Or another method of making this work?

Comment: could you provide a short demo to reproduce the issue? You are importing map on the custom comp but you do not use it anywhere inside

Comment: You can ignore the functions of the map. Just know that the map is used to run the animation. There are a lot of functions and it would get very crowded if I paste them all into stack overflow. All I'm interested in is how to run the playStop function from an outside file

Comment: You main issue is that animationTimer is always set to false at the start. I think that you could leverage react hooks in this case. 
Change the  playStop to a boolean that the button can toggle on and off `setPlayStop(! playStop)` that will clean up the Weather component logic a bit. 
And useEffect in Weather that has playStop as a dependency to run a Play or Stop function.